# Beamer: Nodes inside itemize

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, itemize

I am trying to include nodes as items, so that the text is aligned as it was a normal item, but I could still include arrows and boxes as in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Mutated self proteins in tumor cells can be potential antigens presented by HLA-A
        \item
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=left] (A) at (0,0) {Study immune system and cancer cells interactions};
    \node[below=1cm of A, anchor=center, fill=yellow] (B) {Immunotherapies};
    \draw[->, >=latex, blue!40!white, line width=5pt] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following (text not aligned to the item symbol and to the text above, as if it was a normal item; overbox warning):
[image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your `tikzpicture` is too wide for the remaining space on the line, so it gets moved a line down.  To fix this you need to specify a `text width` in the node (or clip the picture, but that would not be helpful).  Just doing that will leave you some alignment problems:

1. you need to specify that thet `anchor` for the node is the `base` of the first line of text, and then use that as the vertical alignment point for the whole picture, by specifying 
   `baseline`
2. then you will notice that your text is indented by amount that comes from the `inner sep` of the node, so you need to put that to `0`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Mutated self proteins in tumor cells can be potential
      antigens presented by HLA-A
        \item%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
      \node[align=left,inner sep=0pt,text width=0.9\linewidth,anchor=base]
      (A) at (0,0) {Study immune system and cancer cells interactions};
      \node[below=1.5cm of A, anchor=center, fill=yellow] (B) {Immunotherapies};
      \draw[->, >=latex, blue!40!white, line width=5pt] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

By the way, I presume you are aware of the `columns` construction in `beamer`, instead of having to use `minipages`.

Comment: Thanks! for some reason I got used to minipages and never actually use columns... is the use of columns recommended over minipages? what are the advantages? Is it worth switching? Thanks again!

Comment: If you are happy with `minipages` that is fine.  One thing one risks is unexpected line breaks between two `minipages`.  Using `columns` the individual `column` environments are guaranteed to be next to each other.